# Can't get my ships to mutate properly. Python Neural Network

Tags: python, class, neural-network, simulation

I've been tinkering with neural networks and have some simple code that almost works. The only problem is that my network will not mutate properly. I've tested the network class on its own and it will mutate but it doesn't seem to want to mutate when used as a subclass.

```
%matplotlib inline 
#for jupyter

import matplotlib                   #import for plotting results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np                  #np for random and exp
from datetime import datetime as dt #for time seed

#GLOBALS
sp = 100.0            #y setpoint 
seconds = 120         #simulation length
timescale = 0.1       #timestep
generations = 10000   #generations to simulate
population = 20       #number of ships per generation
debug = False         #unused


#NN class
class Network:

    #create array of neuron placeholder values for feedforward function
    def initNeurons(self):
        neuronList = []
        for i in range(len(self.layers)):
            neuronList.append([])
            for j in range(self.layers[i]):
                neuronList[i].append(0)
        self.neurons = neuronList
        #print(self.neurons)

    #randomly generate weights for each neuron based on number of neurons in previous layers
    def initWeights(self):

        weightsList = []
        #for each layer
        for i in range(1,len(self.layers)):

            layerWeights = []
            neuronsInPrevLayer = self.layers[i-1] #number of neurons in previous layer

            #for each neuron in layer
            for j in range(len(self.neurons[i])):
                neuronWeights = []

                #for each neuron in previous layer
                for k in range(neuronsInPrevLayer):                    
                    neuronWeights.append(2*(np.random.rand()-0.5)) #generate random weight (-1-1)

                layerWeights.append(neuronWeights)

            weightsList.append(layerWeights)

        self.weights = weightsList

    #calculate the values of each neuron and return output neurons
    def feedForward(self, netinputs):
        for i in range(len(netinputs)):
            #print(self.neurons[0])
            self.neurons[0][i] = netinputs[i]

        for i in range(1,len(self.layers)):
            for j in range(len(self.neurons[i])):
                value = 0.25

                for k in range(len(self.neurons[i-1])):
                    value += self.weights[i-1][j][k] * self.neurons[i-1][k]
                self.neurons[i][j] = (1/(1+np.exp(-value)))

        return self.neurons[-1]

    #randomly mutate weights while iterating through them
    def mutate(self):
        change = False
        for i in range(len(self.weights)):
            for j in range(len(self.weights[i])):
                for k in range(len(self.weights[i][j])):

                    weight = self.weights[i][j][k]
                    #print(weight)
                    randnum = np.random.rand() * 1000

                    if randnum <= 20:
                        weight *= -1
                        change = True
                    elif randnum <= 40:
                        weight = np.random.rand() - 0.5
                        change = True
                    elif randnum <= 80:
                        weight *= np.random.rand()
                        change = True
                    self.weights[i][j][k] = weight
                    if change and debug:
                        #print('mutation!')
                        pass


    #iterate through weights and copy                
    def copyWeights(self, copyWeight):
        for i in range(len(self.weights)):
            for j in range(len(self.weights[i])):
                for k in range(len(self.weights[i][j])):
                    self.weights[i][j][k] = copyWeight[i][j][k]   

    #copies the weights from a passed NN          
    def Network(self, copyNetwork):
        self.layers = []
        self.neurons = []
        self.weights = []
        self.fitness = -9000.0
        for i in range(len(copyNetwork.layers)):
            self.layers.append(copyNetwork.layers[i])

        np.random.seed(dt.now().microsecond)
        self.initNeurons()
        self.initWeights()
        self.copyWeights(copyNetwork.weights)

    #INITIALIZATION FUNCTION
    #initializes NN given an array of neuron counts EX: [3,5,3,1] 3 input neurons 1 output neuron with 2 hidden layers
    def __init__(self, inLayers ):
        self.layers = []    #array with neurons per layer ex: [2,4,2] 
        self.neurons = []   #placeholder array for neuron values for feedforward
        self.weights = []   #weight values for each layer and neuron
        self.fitness = -9000.0 #initial fitness set to nonsense value
        for i in range(len(inLayers)):
            self.layers.append(inLayers[i])

        np.random.seed(dt.now().microsecond) #seed for RNG
        self.initNeurons()                   #create arrays for sotring neuron values
        self.initWeights()                   #create weights for calculating neuron values



#environment for ship simulation
class environment(object):
    def __init__(self): # initialize self when created
        self.objects = []
        self.t = 0
        self.dt = timescale
        self.seconds = seconds
    def init(self): #initialize ships
        for p in self.objects:
            p.init()
    def start(self): #iterate through time and call step for each ship
        for i in range(0, self.seconds*100, int(self.dt*100)):
            self.t += self.dt
            #if i % 10 == 0:
                #print(self.t)
            for p in self.objects:
                p.step()

class ship():
    def __init__(self, m, x, y, v, thrust_max, throttle, env):
        self.brain = Network([3,8,4,3,2])   #create NN for throttle control with 3 inputs and 2 outputs
        self.deltasp = []                   #array for difference from setpoint per step for plotting and analysis
        self.yset = []                      #array for y coord (height) per step for plotting and analysis
        self.mass = m                       #mass for force and acceleration calculation
        self.x = x                          #initial x value
        self.y = y                          #initial y value
        self.velocity = v                   #initial velocity
        self.thrust_max = thrust_max        #maximum thrust
        self.throttle = throttle/100.0      #initial throttle
        self.a = 0.0                        #initial acceleration        
        env.objects.append(self)            #add ship to environment objects
        self.env = env                      

    def init(self):
        self.deltasp = [] #array for difference from setpoint per step for plotting and analysis
        self.yset = []    #array for y coord (height) per step for plotting and analysis
        self.x = 0        #x coord for plotting (unused)
        self.y = 0        #y coord (height)
        self.velocity = 0 #ship velocity
        self.a = 0        #ship acceleration

    #calculate acceleration based on thrust throttle and mass minus acceleration due to gravity    
    def acc(self):
        return ((self.thrust_max*self.throttle)/(self.mass))-9.8

    def step(self): #ship step

        #get outputs from NN
        self.outputs = self.brain.feedForward([self.throttle,self.a,((self.y)-sp)])

        #if output 1 is high increase thrust by variable amount based on certainty
        if self.outputs[0] >= 0.6:
            self.throttle += self.outputs[0]-0.5
            #print('throttle up')
        #if output 2 is high decrease thrust by variable amount based on certainty
        elif self.outputs[1] >= 0.6:
            self.throttle -= self.outputs[1]-0.5

        #throttle limiting between 0% and 100% (0-1)
        if self.throttle <= 0:
            self.throttle = 0
        elif self.throttle >= 1:
            self.throttle = 1

        #store delta from setpoint to array for plotting and analysis
        self.deltasp.append(abs(self.y-sp))

        #increase x arbitrarily (legacy code from turtle version could be useful later)
        self.x += 0.1

        #increase y (height) by timestep times velocity
        self.y += self.env.dt*self.velocity

        #calculate new acceleration
        self.a = self.acc()

        #limit height to 0 
        #floor collision detection
        if self.y < 0:
            self.a = 0
            self.velocity = 0
            self.y = 0

        #store y coord (height) for plotting and analysis            
        self.yset.append(self.y)

        #calculate new velocity based on acceleration and timestep
        self.velocity = self.velocity + self.env.dt*self.a

        #calculate fitness as summation of difference from setpoint
        self.brain.fitness = sum(self.deltasp)

    #mutate NN for evolution
    def evolve(self):
        self.brain.mutate()

def bubble_sort(seq): #modified bubblesort borrowed from http://python3.codes/popular-sorting-algorithms/
    for ob in seq:
        #print(ob.brain.weights)
        pass
    changed = True
    while changed:
        changed = False
        for i in range(len(seq) - 1):
            if abs(seq[i].brain.fitness) < abs(seq[i+1].brain.fitness):
                seq[i], seq[i+1] = seq[i+1], seq[i]
                changed = True
    return None

def reproduce(ships): #make new ships based on fitness
    mute_ships = []
    return_ships = []

    for o in ships:
        mute_ships.append(o)

    bubble_sort(mute_ships) #sort ships by fitness

    for i in range(len(ships)): #create array of mutated best ship
        mute_ships[-1].evolve()
        return_ships.append(mute_ships[-1]) 

    return return_ships #array of mutated ships

def main(): #main loop
    new_ships = [] #mutated ships container

    for gen in range(generations): #loop for generations
        ships = []
        env = environment()

        if gen == 0:# if first generation generate initial population
            for i in range(population): 
                np.random.seed(dt.now().microsecond)
                shp = ship(500.0, -100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9800.0, 0.0, env)
                ships.append(shp)

        else: #if not first generation copy ships from mutated ships
            ships = new_ships
            for o in ships:
                o.env.objects.append(o)
            new_ships = []

        env.init()   #initialize environment
        env.start()  #start environment simulation

        for o in reproduce(ships):#mutate ships
            new_ships.append(o)

        del env

###     DEBUGGING    ###
        #print(len(new_ships))
        #print(ships[0].brain.weights == new_ships[0].brain.weights)
        #if ships[0].brain.weights == new_ships[0].brain.weights:
            #print('no mutations')
        #print("generation: ", gen + 1)
        #for o in ships:
            #print(o.brain.fitness)
            #plt.plot(range(len(o.yset)),o.yset)

    #print(ships[0].brain.fitness)

    for o in ships:    #plot different statistics
        #print(o.brain.fitness)
        plt.plot(range(len(o.yset)),o.yset)
        #plt.plot(range(len(o.deltasp)),o.deltasp)

    return "done"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

At this point I'm pretty stuck. Sorry for some of the spaghetti code. I've tried to clean it up a bit.

Comment: I new to neural networks in python, I just want to know, is this reinforcement learning?

Comment: The code needs a lot more cleaning up.

Comment: @RobertAltena helpful

Comment: @messy212 no this is genetic or trying to be at least.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I see:

1. In `reproduce()` you are doing a bunch of weird things:

   - you sort the list (which has no effect on the mutation), then mutate them (which probably destroys the sorted-ness);
   - you iterate with an index into the array, which is usually unPythonic, but operate on `mute_ships[-1]` each time - which means that, with 20 ships, you are mutating the last ship 20 times and the others not at all!
   - `.evolve()` seems to be an in-place operation, but you copy the result into a new list to return; then in the calling function, `main()`, you copy the result into a new list **again** using a loop (the slow way) instead of using the `list()` constructor (simpler and faster)
   - that makes no difference anyway, because the list only contains references to the same ship instances anyway!

   Instead, try

   ```
   def reproduce(ships):
       for ship in ships:
           ship.evolve()
   ```
2. Naming conventions: PEP8 says classes should be capitalized, methods should be lowercase. Also, some of the variable names are nasty (`o.env.objects.append(o)`?)
3. You don't need bubblesort; you can just do `mute_ships = sorted(ships, key = lambda ship: ship.brain.fitness`. That replaces about 16 lines of code.
4. You aren't evolving the ships or environments at all, so separate classes for them are kind of overkill. I would probably rename Network to ShipController, and stick the whole simulation into a ShipController.evaluate() method.
5. `np.random` seeds itself quite happily; the only good reason to seed it yourself is if you want to be able to repeat a run by giving it the same seed again. Also, `np.random.seed()` expects a value in 0 .. 4.3 billion; you are giving it a value in 0 .. 1 million. By doing so, you are *greatly reducing* the actual randomness of your algorithm.
6. You have a global `sp` but also an `sp` in `main()` which never gets used, which will confuse you if you ever try to change it.
7. You are not really using `numpy` properly; it works best on vectorized blocks of calculations, not lots of little split-up calculations inside Python loops.

Comment: 1. I'm only trying to copy the ship with the highest fitness and use mutations of that one to create the next population which is why I use the index -1. Then the simulation runs again and does the same for the next ship with the highest fitness.
2. I just use o short for object.
3. Thank you I'll use this instead.

4. They're multiple classes because I took two different projects I had and kinda crammed them together.
4. That's just how I have it setup currently but I am trying to evolve the ship controller by survival of the fittest.
5. Ok
6. Noted
7. I get less errors.